# how to stop TableViewCell from repeating images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm importing contacts into my application and inserting them into a tableview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: importCellId, for: indexPath) as! tbcImportContact
    cell.contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

When I set a contacts image like I am doing here:

```
var contact: Contact? {
    didSet {
        if let name = contact?.name {
            nameLabel.text = name
        } else {
            nameLabel.text = ""
        }
        if let img = contact?.contactImage {
            contactImage.image = img
        } else {
            contactImage.image = UIImage(named: "emptyProfile")
        }
    }
```

The next contact with a `nil` image should receive the `UIImage(named: "emptyProfile")` but instead the contact is assigned the previous contacts image.

I have tried adding that `else` statement to prevent this but it doesn't work.
I have also tried adding:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.contactImage.image = UIImage(named: "emptyProfile")
    self.nameLabel.text = ""
}
```

to reset the cells when assigning a contact to it but that also did not work.
I also tried setting it async on the main thread and that also did not work.

Any suggestions on what else I can try to fix this?

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint on the `if let img...` line and see what it was doing for your different cases.  (E.g. whether the contact was the one I expected and what happened for either a valid or empty image property)

Comment: @PhillipMills the contact image come in nil untill the first contact that has an image gets set, then after if the contact image is nil, it brings back the image from the contact before that was not nil

Comment: What code does that?  Does `if let img` evaluate to true?

Comment: @PhillipMills yes it evaluates to true. I am setting the cell.contact = contacts[indexPath.row], thats when it enters the didSet and for some reason the contact stays with the image of the previous contact

Comment: Good to know.  That sounds like it's something with the contacts array rather than how you're using the table.

Comment: According to apple doc, content changes should be made in the cellForRow delegate method and not in `prepareForReuse` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse?language=objc

Comment: @MikeM yeah i had also tried adding the code to set the images at prepareForReuse but that ended up not working either

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just setting the image for the cell when i import the contacts like this:

```
  if let imageData = contact.imageData {
                    image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                } else {
                    image = UIImage(named: "contactProfile")
                }
```

here is the code on how i import the contacts:

```
do {
        let keysToFetch = keys as [CNKeyDescriptor]
        try contactsStore.enumerateContacts(with: CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)) {
            (contact, cursor) -> Void in
            for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
                let phoneNumberString = phoneNumber.value.stringValue
                if let imageData = contact.imageData {
                    image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                } else {
                    image = UIImage(named: "contactProfile")
                }

                let emailAddress = contact.emailAddresses.count > 0 ? contact.emailAddresses[0].value : ""
                let postalAddress = contact.postalAddresses.count > 0 ? "\(contact.postalAddresses[0].value)" : ""                    
                self.contacts.append(Contact(name: contact.givenName, phoneNumber: phoneNumberString, contactImage: image, email: emailAddress as String , address: postalAddress))
            }
        }

        if contacts.count == 0 {
            message = "No contacts found."
        }
    } catch {
        message = "Unable to fetch contacts."
    }
```